# Scrolling in right to left in table view Library

Tags: android, tableview

I use the TableView library to create a table for sql data by filtering, clicking, scrolling, sorting, and so on.

https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView

This library is very good for me, but there is an error in the rtl scroll, and I want to use rtl table .
When it's only scrolling horizontally, it's a good job.
When it only moves vertically, a good job is done.
But when the horizontal scrolling and then moving together vertically, the table breaks down.
I guess,The reason is (probably) TableView doens't store the scroll postion according to the activity lifecycle.
I Guess, the problem is in the HorizontalRecyclerViewListener class and the VerticalRecyclerViewListener class. but i Incapable to fix it.

is there anyone to can fix this bug?

bug screenshot:

http://atighsoft.ir/download/a.jpg

http://atighsoft.ir/download/b.jpg

HorizontalRecyclerViewListener class:

```
 package com.evrencoskun.tableview.listener.scroll;

 import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
 import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;

 import com.evrencoskun.tableview.ITableView;
 import com.evrencoskun.tableview.adapter.recyclerview.CellRecyclerView;

 /**
  * Created by evrencoskun on 19/06/2017.
  */

 public class HorizontalRecyclerViewListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener implements
         RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

     private static final String LOG_TAG = HorizontalRecyclerViewListener.class.getSimpleName();

     private CellRecyclerView mColumnHeaderRecyclerView;
     private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mCellLayoutManager;
     private RecyclerView mLastTouchedRecyclerView;

     // X position means column position
     private int mXPosition;
     private boolean mIsMoved;

     private int mScrollPosition;
     private int mScrollPositionOffset = 0;

     private RecyclerView mCurrentRVTouched = null;

     private VerticalRecyclerViewListener mVerticalRecyclerViewListener;

     public HorizontalRecyclerViewListener(ITableView tableView) {
         this.mColumnHeaderRecyclerView = tableView.getColumnHeaderRecyclerView();
         this.mCellLayoutManager = tableView.getCellRecyclerView().getLayoutManager();
         this.mVerticalRecyclerViewListener = tableView.getVerticalRecyclerViewListener();
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

         // Prevent multitouch, once we start to listen with a RV,
         // we ignore any other RV until the touch is released (UP)
         if (mCurrentRVTouched != null && rv != mCurrentRVTouched) {
             return true;
         }

         if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
             mCurrentRVTouched = rv;
             if (rv.getScrollState() == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                 if (mLastTouchedRecyclerView != null && rv != mLastTouchedRecyclerView) {
                     if (mLastTouchedRecyclerView == mColumnHeaderRecyclerView) {
                         mColumnHeaderRecyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(this);
                         mColumnHeaderRecyclerView.stopScroll();
                         Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Scroll listener  has been removed to " +
                                 "mColumnHeaderRecyclerView at last touch control");
                     } else {
                         int lastTouchedIndex = getIndex(mLastTouchedRecyclerView);

                         // Control whether the last touched recyclerView is still attached or not
                         if (lastTouchedIndex >= 0 && lastTouchedIndex < mCellLayoutManager
                                 .getChildCount()) {
                             // Control the scroll listener is already removed. For instance; if user
                             // scroll the parent recyclerView vertically, at that time,
                             // ACTION_CANCEL
                             // will be triggered that removes the scroll listener of the last
                             // touched
                             // recyclerView.
                             if (!((CellRecyclerView) mLastTouchedRecyclerView)
                                     .isHorizontalScrollListenerRemoved()) {
                                 // Remove scroll listener of the last touched recyclerView
                                 // Because user touched another recyclerView before the last one get
                                 // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE state that removes the scroll listener
                                 ((RecyclerView) mCellLayoutManager.getChildAt(lastTouchedIndex))
                                         .removeOnScrollListener(this);

                                 Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Scroll listener  has been removed to " +
                                         mLastTouchedRecyclerView.getId() + " CellRecyclerView " +
                                         "at last touch control");

                                 // the last one scroll must be stopped to be sync with others
                                 ((RecyclerView) mCellLayoutManager.getChildAt(lastTouchedIndex))
                                         .stopScroll();
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }

                 mXPosition = ((CellRecyclerView) rv).getScrolledX();
                 rv.addOnScrollListener(this);
                 Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Scroll listener  has been added to " + rv.getId() + " at action "
                         + "down");
             }
         } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
             mCurrentRVTouched = rv;
             // Why does it matter ?
             // user scroll any recyclerView like brushing, at that time, ACTION_UP will be
             // triggered
             // before scrolling. So, we need to store whether it moved or not.
             mIsMoved = true;
         } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
             mCurrentRVTouched = null;
             int nScrollX = ((CellRecyclerView) rv).getScrolledX();
             // Is it just touched without scrolling then remove the listener
             if (mXPosition == nScrollX && !mIsMoved) {
                 rv.removeOnScrollListener(this);
                 Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Scroll listener  has been removed to " + rv.getId() + " at " +
                         "action" + " up");
             }

             mLastTouchedRecyclerView = rv;

         } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
             // ACTION_CANCEL action will be triggered if users try to scroll vertically
             // For this situation, it doesn't matter whether the x position is changed or not
             // Beside this, even if moved action will be triggered, scroll listener won't
             // triggered on cancel action. So, we need to change state of the mIsMoved value as
             // well.

             // Renew the scroll position and its offset
             renewScrollPosition(rv);

             rv.removeOnScrollListener(this);
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Scroll listener  has been removed to " + rv.getId() + " at action " +
                     "cancel");

             mIsMoved = false;

             mLastTouchedRecyclerView = rv;

             mCurrentRVTouched = null;
         }

         return false;
     }

     @Override
     public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
     }

     @Override
     public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
     }

     @Override
     public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
         // Column Header should be scrolled firstly. Because it is the compared recyclerView to
         // make column width fit.

         if (recyclerView == mColumnHeaderRecyclerView) {
             super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

             // Scroll each cell recyclerViews
             for (int i = 0; i < mCellLayoutManager.getChildCount(); i++) {
                 CellRecyclerView child = (CellRecyclerView) mCellLayoutManager.getChildAt(i);
                 // Scroll horizontally
                 child.scrollBy(dx, dy);
             }
         } else {
             // Scroll column header recycler view as well
             //mColumnHeaderRecyclerView.scrollBy(dx, 0);

             super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

             // Scroll each cell recyclerViews except the current touched one
             for (int i = 0; i < mCellLayoutManager.getChildCount(); i++) {
                 CellRecyclerView child = (CellRecyclerView) mCellLayoutManager.getChildAt(i);
                 if (child != recyclerView) {
                     // Scroll horizontally
                     child.scrollBy(dx, 0);
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
         super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

         if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
             // Renew the scroll position and its offset
             renewScrollPosition(recyclerView);

             recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(this);
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Scroll listener has been removed to " + recyclerView.getId() + " at "
                     + "onScrollStateChanged");
             mIsMoved = false;

             // When a user scrolls horizontally, VerticalRecyclerView add vertical scroll
             // listener because of touching process.However, mVerticalRecyclerViewListener
             // doesn't know anything about it. So, it is necessary to remove the last touched
             // recyclerView which uses the mVerticalRecyclerViewListener.
             boolean isNeeded = mLastTouchedRecyclerView != mColumnHeaderRecyclerView;
             mVerticalRecyclerViewListener.removeLastTouchedRecyclerViewScrollListener(isNeeded);
         }
     }

     private int getIndex(RecyclerView rv) {
         for (int i = 0; i < mCellLayoutManager.getChildCount(); i++) {
             if (mCellLayoutManager.getChildAt(i) == rv) {
                 return i;
             }
         }
         return -1;
     }


     /**
      * This method calculates the current scroll position and its offset to help new attached
      * recyclerView on window at that position and offset
      *
      * @see #getScrollPosition()
      * @see #getScrollPositionOffset()
      */
     private void renewScrollPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
         LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
         mScrollPosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

         // That means there is no completely visible Position.
         if (mScrollPosition == -1) {
             mScrollPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

             // That means there is just a visible item on the screen
             if (mScrollPosition == layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()) {
                 // in this case we use the position which is the last & first visible item.
             } else {
                 // That means there are 2 visible item on the screen. However, second one is not
                 // completely visible.
                 mScrollPosition = mScrollPosition + 1;
             }
         }

         mScrollPositionOffset = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(mScrollPosition).getLeft();
     }

     /**
      * When parent RecyclerView scrolls vertically, the child horizontal recycler views should be
      * displayed on right scroll position. So the first complete visible position of the
      * recyclerView is stored as a member to use it for a new attached recyclerview whose
      * orientation is horizontal as well.
      *
      * @see #getScrollPositionOffset()
      */
     public int getScrollPosition() {
         return mScrollPosition;
     }

     /**
      * Users can scroll the recyclerViews to the any x position which may not the exact position. So
      * we need to know store the offset value to locate a specific location for a new attached
      * recyclerView
      *
      * @see #getScrollPosition()
      */
     public int getScrollPositionOffset() {
         return mScrollPositionOffset;
     }

     public void setScrollPositionOffset(int offset) {
         mScrollPositionOffset = offset;
     }

     /**
      * To change default scroll position that is before TableView is not populated.
      */
     public void setScrollPosition(int position) {
         this.mScrollPosition = position;
     }
 }
```

VerticalRecyclerViewListener class :

```
 package com.evrencoskun.tableview.listener.scroll;

 import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;

 import com.evrencoskun.tableview.ITableView;
 import com.evrencoskun.tableview.adapter.recyclerview.CellRecyclerView;

 /**
  * Created by evrencoskun on 30/06/2017.
  */

 public class VerticalRecyclerViewListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener implements
         RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

     private static final String LOG_TAG = VerticalRecyclerViewListener.class.getSimpleName();

     private CellRecyclerView mRowHeaderRecyclerView, mCellRecyclerView;
     private RecyclerView mLastTouchedRecyclerView;

     // Y Position means row position
     private int mYPosition;
     private boolean mIsMoved;


     private RecyclerView mCurrentRVTouched = null;


     public VerticalRecyclerViewListener(ITableView tableView) {
         this.mRowHeaderRecyclerView = tableView.getRowHeaderRecyclerView();
         this.mCellRecyclerView = tableView.getCellRecyclerView();
     }


     private float dx = 0, dy = 0;

     /**
      * +     * check which direction the user is scrolling
      * +     * @param ev
      * +     * @return
      * +
      */


     private boolean verticalDirection(MotionEvent ev) {
         if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
             if (dx == 0) {
                 dx = ev.getX();

             }
             if (dy == 0) {
                 dy = ev.getY();

             }
             float xdiff = Math.abs(dx - ev.getX());
             float ydiff = Math.abs(dy - ev.getY());
             dx = ev.getX();
             dy = ev.getY();

             // if user scrolled more horizontally than vertically
             if (xdiff > ydiff) {
                 return false;

             }

         }

         return true;

     }


     @Override
     public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

         // If scroll direction is not Vertical, then ignore and reset last RV touched
        if (!verticalDirection(e)) {
             mCurrentRVTouched = null;
             return false;

         }

         // Prevent multitouch, once we start to listen with a RV,
         // we ignore any other RV until the touch is released (UP)
         if ((mCurrentRVTouched != null && rv != mCurrentRVTouched)) {
             return true;

         }

         if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
             mCurrentRVTouched = rv;
             if (rv.getScrollState() == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                 if (mLastTouchedRecyclerView != null && rv != mLastTouchedRecyclerView) {
                     removeLastTouchedRecyclerViewScrollListener(false);
                 }
                 mYPosition = ((CellRecyclerView) rv).getScrolledY();
                 rv.addOnScrollListener(this);

                 if (rv == mCellRecyclerView) {
                     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mCellRecyclerView scroll listener added");
                 } else if (rv == mRowHeaderRecyclerView) {
                     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mRowHeaderRecyclerView scroll listener added");
                 }

                 // Refresh the value;
                 mIsMoved = false;
             }
         } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
             mCurrentRVTouched = rv;
             // Why does it matter ?
             // user scroll any recyclerView like brushing, at that time, ACTION_UP will be
             // triggered
             // before scrolling. So, we need to store whether it moved or not.
             mIsMoved = true;
         } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
             mCurrentRVTouched = null;
             int nScrollY = ((CellRecyclerView) rv).getScrolledY();

             // TODO: Even if moved value is true and it may not scroll. This should be fixed.
             // TODO: The scenario is scroll lightly center RecyclerView vertically.
             // TODO: Below if condition may be changed later.

             // Is it just touched without scrolling then remove the listener
             if (mYPosition == nScrollY && !mIsMoved && rv.getScrollState() == RecyclerView
                     .SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                 rv.removeOnScrollListener(this);

                 if (rv == mCellRecyclerView) {
                     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mCellRecyclerView scroll listener removed from up ");
                 } else if (rv == mRowHeaderRecyclerView) {
                     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mRowHeaderRecyclerView scroll listener removed from up");
                 }
             }

             mLastTouchedRecyclerView = rv;

         }

         return false;
     }

     @Override
     public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
     }

     @Override
     public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
     }

     @Override
     public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
         // CellRecyclerViews should be scrolled after the RowHeaderRecyclerView.
         // Because it is one of the main compared criterion to make each columns fit.

         if (recyclerView == mCellRecyclerView) {

                 super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

             // The below code has been moved in CellLayoutManager
          //   mRowHeaderRecyclerView.scrollBy(0, dy);

         } else if (recyclerView == mRowHeaderRecyclerView) {
             super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

             mCellRecyclerView.scrollBy(0, dy);
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
         super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
             recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(this);
             mIsMoved = false;

             mCurrentRVTouched = null;
             if (recyclerView == mCellRecyclerView) {
                 Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mCellRecyclerView scroll listener removed from " +
                         "onScrollStateChanged");
             } else if (recyclerView == mRowHeaderRecyclerView) {
                 Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mRowHeaderRecyclerView scroll listener removed from " +
                         "onScrollStateChanged");
             }
         }
     }

     /**
      * If current recyclerView that is touched to scroll is not same as the last one, this method
      * helps to remove the scroll listener of the last touched recyclerView.
      * This method is a little bit different from HorizontalRecyclerViewListener.
      *
      * @param isNeeded Is mCellRecyclerView scroll listener should be removed ? The scenario is a
      *                 user scrolls vertically using RowHeaderRecyclerView. After that, the user
      *                 scrolls horizontally using ColumnHeaderRecyclerView.
      */
     public void removeLastTouchedRecyclerViewScrollListener(boolean isNeeded) {

         if (mLastTouchedRecyclerView == mCellRecyclerView) {
             mCellRecyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(this);
             mCellRecyclerView.stopScroll();
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mCellRecyclerView scroll listener removed from last touched");
         } else {
             mRowHeaderRecyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(this);
             mRowHeaderRecyclerView.stopScroll();
             Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mRowHeaderRecyclerView scroll listener removed from last touched");
             if (isNeeded) {
                 mCellRecyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(this);
                 mCellRecyclerView.stopScroll();
                 Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mCellRecyclerView scroll listener removed from last touched");
             }

         }
     }
 }
```

ScrollHandler class:

```js
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2018. Evren Coşkun
 *
 *  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 *  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 *  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 *
 */

package com.evrencoskun.tableview.handler;

import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;

import com.evrencoskun.tableview.ITableView;
import com.evrencoskun.tableview.layoutmanager.CellLayoutManager;
import com.evrencoskun.tableview.layoutmanager.ColumnHeaderLayoutManager;
import com.evrencoskun.tableview.layoutmanager.ColumnLayoutManager;

/**
 * Created by evrencoskun on 13.01.2018.
 */

public class ScrollHandler {
    private ITableView mTableView;
    private CellLayoutManager mCellLayoutManager;
    private LinearLayoutManager mRowHeaderLayoutManager;
    private ColumnHeaderLayoutManager mColumnHeaderLayoutManager;

    public ScrollHandler(ITableView tableView) {
        this.mTableView = tableView;
        this.mCellLayoutManager = tableView.getCellLayoutManager();
        this.mRowHeaderLayoutManager = tableView.getRowHeaderLayoutManager();
        this.mColumnHeaderLayoutManager = tableView.getColumnHeaderLayoutManager();
    }

    public void scrollToColumnPosition(int columnPosition) {
        // TableView is not on screen yet.
        if (!((View) mTableView).isShown()) {
            // Change default value of the listener
            mTableView.getHorizontalRecyclerViewListener().setScrollPosition(columnPosition);
        }

        // Column Header should be scrolled firstly because of fitting column width process.
        scrollColumnHeader(columnPosition, 0);
        scrollCellHorizontally(columnPosition, 0);
    }

    public void scrollToColumnPosition(int columnPosition, int offset) {
        // TableView is not on screen yet.
        if (!((View) mTableView).isShown()) {
            // Change default value of the listener
            mTableView.getHorizontalRecyclerViewListener().setScrollPosition(columnPosition);
            mTableView.getHorizontalRecyclerViewListener().setScrollPositionOffset(offset);
        }

        // Column Header should be scrolled firstly because of fitting column width process.
        scrollColumnHeader(columnPosition, offset);
        scrollCellHorizontally(columnPosition, offset);
    }

    public void scrollToRowPosition(int rowPosition) {
        mRowHeaderLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(rowPosition);
        mCellLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(rowPosition);
    }

    public void scrollToRowPosition(int rowPosition, int offset) {
        mRowHeaderLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(rowPosition, offset);
        mCellLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(rowPosition, offset);
    }

    private void scrollCellHorizontally(int columnPosition, int offset) {
        CellLayoutManager cellLayoutManager = mTableView.getCellLayoutManager();

        for (int i = cellLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition(); i < cellLayoutManager
                .findLastVisibleItemPosition() + 1; i++) {

            RecyclerView cellRowRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) cellLayoutManager
                    .findViewByPosition(i);

            if (cellRowRecyclerView != null) {
                ColumnLayoutManager columnLayoutManager = (ColumnLayoutManager)
                        cellRowRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();

                columnLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(columnPosition, offset);
            }

        }
    }

    private void scrollColumnHeader(int columnPosition, int offset) {
        mTableView.getColumnHeaderLayoutManager().scrollToPositionWithOffset(columnPosition,
                offset);
    }

    public int getColumnPosition() {
        return mColumnHeaderLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    }

    public int getColumnPositionOffset() {
        View child = mColumnHeaderLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(mColumnHeaderLayoutManager
                .findFirstVisibleItemPosition());
        if(child != null) {
            return child.getRight();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public int getRowPosition() {
        return mRowHeaderLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    }

    public int getRowPositionOffset() {
        View child = mRowHeaderLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(mRowHeaderLayoutManager
                .findFirstVisibleItemPosition());
        if(child != null) {
            return child.getRight();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you used this https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableViewSampleApp , can we have edittext for the table cells and capture the edited text using in thisTableView?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use one or both of their supported methods:

```
scrollToColumnPosition(int column)
scrollToRowPosition(int row)
```